# MS SQL FIFO Partial transfers

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

I have a number of transactions that transfer inventory from one account to another account. I can transfer all inventory and I can transfer partial inventory.

I need to pay commission to the owner of the account where inventory resides at my commission date.

My report needs to show the original origin of the inventory items if they have transferred and provide a unit_balance that I can calculate commission from.

**Example Transactions:**

**Account 100**
Account, trxid, transacted_units, transactiontype, transferfrom, transferto, date
100, 1, 100, buy, NULL, NULL, 1/1/2020
100, 2, 50, transfer in, 200, NULL, 1/2/2020

**Account 200**
Account, trxid, transacted_units, transactiontype, transferfrom, transferto, date
200, 3, 40, buy, NULL, NULL, 12/1/2019
200, 4, 30, buy, NULL, NULL, 12/2/2019
200, 5, 7, sell, NULL, NULL, 12/3/2019
200, 6, 50, transfer out, NULL, 100, 1/2/2020

---

My report output needs to show the full details of accounts associated with the inventory that relates to the unit_balance

**Report Output:**
[level], Account, trxid, parenttrxid, transacted_units, transactiontype, transferfrom, transferto, date, units_balance
0, 100, 1, NULL, 100, buy, NULL, NULL, 1/1/2020, 100
0, 100, 2, NULL, 50, transfer in, 200, NULL, 1/2/2020, NULL
1, 200, 3, 2, 40, buy, NULL, NULL, 12/1/2019, 33
1, 200, 4, 2, 30, buy, NULL, NULL, 12/2/2019, 17
1, 200, 5, 2, 7, sell, NULL, NULL, 12/3/2019, 0
1, 200, 6, 2, 50, transfer out, NULL, 100, 1/2/2020, 0

*The FIFO logic applies the 7 units sold to the first buy for account 200. The transfer out should then calculate the units_balance on the remaining eligible transactions.

The SQL code I have today only works when I transfer out the full inventory amount, not partial transfers:

```
    select
        [level],
        parentid,
        trxid,
        account,
        transactiontype,
        date,
        rnk,
        transacted_units,
        cumulative,
        CASE 
            WHEN cumulative>0 and transacted_units>=cumulative THEN cumulative
            WHEN cumulative>0 and transacted_units<cumulative THEN transacted_units 
            ELSE 0 
        END units_bal
    from (
        select
            *, 
            sum(transacted_units*Positive_Negative_Indicator) over (partition by parenttrxid, account order by rnk, date, trxid RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) cumulative
        from (

            select *,       
                CASE 
                    WHEN transacted_units*Positive_Negative_Indicator < 0 THEN 0 
                    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parenttrxid, account ORDER BY Positive_Negative_Indicator ASC, date ASC, trxid ASC) 
                END rnk
            from Transactions

        ) a
    ) a
```

The positive_negative_indicator field represents the direction of a transaction. A sell or transfer out is negative whereas the others are positive.

Comment: I don't see how the `units_balance` values in your example matches the source data.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I have edited the result. It should balance now: 150 units in account 100. 100 units direct into account 100 and 50 units from account 200 (33 and 17)

Comment: I thought that `units_balance` of account 100 should become 150. And `units_balance` of account 200 would be 40, then 70, then 63, then 13.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov no, the purpose of the report is to identify the units eligible for commission. I run the report for account 100 which shows 150 units eligible for commission; however, I need to see the original transactions for the units. Units are purchased in 3 different transactions:  

account 100 has 100 unit buy  
account 200 has 40 unit buy (minus the 7 unit sell, makes 33 units eligible for commission)  
account 200 has 30 unit buy (which 17 are eligible for commission)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic. Maybe somebody else would figure it out.

Comment: I believe the key to this is to process the each subset of records by level (not including level 0) first. Most likely apply fifo to the 200 level transactions first, then run the case statement for the unit balance on the updated transacted unit value. I am just not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

for each current "in" transaction, calculate the running total (of units) for the previous "in" transactions. Then assign as many "out" units that haven't been consumed by the previous "in" transactions (as many "out" units== running total of "out" units, that can be consumed by the current "in" transaction).

```
declare @t table
(
    Account int, 
    trxid int,
    trunits int,
    trtype varchar(20),
    transfrom int,
    transto int,
    thedate date
);

insert into @t(Account, trxid, trunits, trtype, transfrom, transto, thedate)
values
(100, 1, 100, 'buy', NULL, NULL, '20200101'),
(100, 2, 50, 'transfer in', 200, NULL, '20200201'),
(200, 3, 40, 'buy', NULL, NULL, '20190112'),
(200, 4, 30, 'buy', NULL, NULL, '20190213'),
(200, 5, 10, 'buy', NULL, NULL, '20190214'),
(200, 6, 7, 'sell', NULL, NULL, '20190315'),
(200, 7, 9, 'sell', NULL, NULL, '20190316'),
(200, 8, 25, 'buy', NULL, NULL, '20190317'),
(200, 9, 39, 'sell', NULL, NULL, '20190318'),
(200, 10, 18, 'sell', NULL, NULL, '20190319'),
(200, 11, 14, 'sell', NULL, NULL, '20190320'),
(200, 11, 50, 'transfer out', NULL, 100, '20200201');



select *, case when t.trtype not in ('sell', 'transfer out') then t.trunits -isnull(otu.out_units, 0) else null end as leftover_units
from 
(
select *, sum(case when trtype not in ('sell', 'transfer out') then trunits else 0 end) over (partition by Account order by thedate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as previous_in_running_units
from @t
) as t
outer apply
(
    select top (1) ort.out_units_running_total - isnull(t.previous_in_running_units, 0) as out_units
    from
    (
        select sum(o.trunits) over(order by o.thedate) as out_units_running_total
        from @t as o
        where o.trtype in ('sell', 'transfer out')
        and o.Account = t.Account
        and t.trtype not in ('sell', 'transfer out') --no calculations needed when cross applying for "out" transactions
    ) as ort --out running totals
    where ort.out_units_running_total-isnull(t.previous_in_running_units, 0) <= t.trunits --<-- ("in") use as many out units as can be consumed by current t.transaction/date after deducting what has been consumed by the previous t.transaction/date
    and ort.out_units_running_total-isnull(t.previous_in_running_units, 0) > 0 --not needed(?) if balance is guaranteed.. total_out = total_in 
    order by ort.out_units_running_total desc 
) as otu; --"out units"
```

Comment: I think this is really close, but I am some of the values do not add up. The "leftover_units" for account 200 needs to reconcile to the transfer into account 100. Your example shows 64 units leftover.

Comment: In addition, your running total of account 200 is 18 units after adding up buy and sells. This needs to be equal or greater than the amount that will be transferred out.@lptr

Comment: i cannot say it is that close. I thought you wanted a conditional FIFO, more like FI-FOCond(Cond:out only when the "out" transaction can be fully consumed by "in" transactions). As for the total of Account 200, the balance is not correct (Account:200, UnitsIn:105, UnitsOut:137) as it was a leftover to check if  FIFOCond wouldn't create negative leftovers. I think what you need is more simple: deduct the sell units from the "in"(buy, transfer in) units in a FIFO fashion and distribute the "transfer out" over the remainder/leftover of each "in" transaction.